# launching docker for windows and not able to start

Tags: docker

While opening `Docker desktop` for the Sitecore project it's giving me the following popup with msg: `Current operation failed because Window policy "Deny write access to fixed drives not protected by Bitlocker" is enabled. Please disable it and retry the operation`. Because of this, I am not able to start the `Docker desktop`

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

step 1: Open Command Prompt and Type: regedit

It will open the `registry editor`

step 2: Go to the following location `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE` and double click on FDVDenyWriteAccess and update the data value to `0`

[image]

now retry the operation.